# ADF get property "status": "Succeeded" and IF for validation

Tags: azure, if-statement, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that pull out data from external and sink into SQL Server table as staging. Process for getting raw data has already succeeded by using 4 `'Copy data'`. Because of so many columns (250 columns), so I split them. [image: this is a pipeline]
What the next requirement validate 4 those 'Copy data' by getting succeeded status. The output of `'Copy data'` look like this

```
    {
    "dataRead": 4772214,
    "dataWritten": 106918,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 1,
    "rowsRead": 1366,
    "rowsCopied": 1366,
    "copyDuration": 8,
    "throughput": 582.546,
    "errors": [],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (Southeast Asia)",
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "DataMovement",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "RestService"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                "region": "Southeast Asia"
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "start": "2022-04-13T07:16:48.5905628Z",
            "duration": 8,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 4
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 4,
                    "details": {
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "RestService",
                            "workingDuration": 1,
                            "timeToFirstByte": 1
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 4,
                "timeToFirstByte": 1,
                "transferDuration": 3
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "NotVerified"
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

Now, I want to get `"status": "Succeeded"` (JSON output) for validating in the `'IF Condition'`.  So, I set Value from variable in the dynamic content `@activity('copy_data_Kobo_MBS').output`

[image]

but when it run, I got error

> The variable 'copy_Kobo_MBS' of type 'Boolean' cannot be initialized
> or updated with value of type 'Object'. The variable 'copy_Kobo_MBS'
> only supports values of types 'Boolean'.

And the question is how to get `"status": "Succeeded"` (JSON output) as 'Variable' value ? So 'IF condition' can examine the 'Variable' value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below expression to pull the run status from the `copy data` activity. As your variable is of Boolean type, you need to evaluate it using the **@equals()** function which returns `true` or `false`.

```
@equals(activity('Copy data1').output.executionDetails[0].status,'Succeeded')
```

As per knowledge, you don’t have to extract the status from copy data activity as you are connecting your copy activity to set variable activity upon success.

That means your set variable activity runs only when your copy data activity ran successfully.

Also, note that

1. If the `copy data` activity (or any other activity) **fails**, then the activities which are added upon the success output of the previous activity will not be running.
2. And if you are connecting more than 1 activity output to a single activity, it only runs when all the connected activities run.
3. You can add activities upon failure or upon completion to process further.

**Example:**

In the below snip, the `Set Variable` activity is not run as copy data is not successful. And `Wait2` activity is not run as all the input activities are not run successfully.

[image]

Comment: From your reply, even tough. It doesn't use 'set variable` and `if condition` will still work base on previous process. Unless one of the 'copy activity' stop because of error.

Comment: Question, how does your `copy activity` make error and halt the next process ? Thxs.

Comment: Hi Daleman, copy activity can be failed due to many reasons, I failed it wantedly to show you the scenario. Here I am trying to show, if any activity fails then the next activity which is connected upon success will not be running. As you can see, in your screenshot `If condition` activity did not run because previous activity failed. The same way if your copy activity gets failed for some reasons your `set variable` activities will not be running. And if your copy activity ran successfully means the status is already succeeded. You don't need to extract the status again with the expression.

Comment: Hey @Daleman, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: yeah I had followed your solution and suggestion. Upvote, done. 